# My cutsom bottom navigation has lag and jump frame when I switch between items

Tags: android, kotlin

I created a custom bottom navigation and when I want navigate from home fragment to plan fragment occurring lag and jump frame but on the contrary is smoother(probably because I used more elements in plan fragment).(the below gif)

I just used 6 ValueAnimators and 1 AnimatorSet to change items position. Also when do several switch it becomes a little smoother.

when I increase animaiton duration (like 1000ms) it is become ok and don't occur jump frame but I do not want this.

Please help me.

[lag in HomeFragment to PlanFragment but  PlanFragment to HomeFragment is smooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHAUO.gif)

Item seleted:

```
 icon.setOnClickListener {
 hideAnimation(iconList[previousItemId - 1]).apply {
                        addListener(onEnd = {
                            previousItemSelectedWidth = itemSelectedWidth

                            showAnimation(icon).apply {
                                start()

                                addListener(onEnd = {
                                    animating = false
                                })
                            }
                        })
                        start()
                    }
}
```

hideAnimation fun:

```
 private fun hideAnimation(previousIcon: ImageView): AnimatorSet {

        val iconScaleAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(previousIcon.scaleX, 1f)
        iconScaleAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                previousIcon.scaleX = it.animatedValue as Float
                previousIcon.scaleY = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        val iconAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(
            previousIcon.y,
            (bottomNavHeight.toFloat() - ((bottomNavHeight - fabRadius) / 2) - (previousIcon.layoutParams.height / 2))
        )
        iconAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                previousIcon.y = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        val fabHideAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(fabRadius, fabRadius * 2)
        fabHideAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                fabY = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        val halfAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(halfCurve.y, fabRadius + 10)
        halfAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                halfCurveCurrent = it.animatedValue as Float
                invalidate()
            }
        }
        val fabShadowAnimator =
            ValueAnimator.ofArgb(Color.parseColor("#35000000"), Color.parseColor("#00000000"))
        fabShadowAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                paintFab.setShadowLayer(10f, 0f, 0f, it.animatedValue as Int)

            }
        }
        val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
        animatorSet.playTogether(
            fabHideAnimator,
            halfAnimator,
            fabShadowAnimator,
            iconAnimator,
            iconScaleAnimator
        )
        animatorSet.duration = animDuration / 2
        animatorSet.interpolator = MotionUtils.resolveThemeInterpolator(
            context,
            com.google.android.material.R.attr.motionEasingEmphasizedAccelerateInterpolator,
            AccelerateInterpolator()
        )
        return animatorSet
    }
```

CurvedBottomNavigation.kt (Full code)

```
class CurvedBottomNavigation @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : BottomNavigationView(context, attrs) {

    private var bottomNavHeight: Int = 0
    private var bottomNavWidth: Int = 0
    private val fabRadius = 100f
    private var fabY = fabRadius

    private val curveOffset = fabRadius * 2
    private val curveHeight = fabRadius + 10f

    private var bottomNavigationOffset = 0f

    private var navBg: Int = Color.WHITE

    private val startCurve: PointF = PointF()
    private val controlPoint1: PointF = PointF()
    private val controlPoint2: PointF = PointF()
    private val halfCurve: PointF = PointF()
    private val controlPoint3: PointF = PointF()
    private val controlPoint4: PointF = PointF()
    private val endCurve: PointF = PointF()

    private var path: Path

    private var paint: Paint
    private var paintFab: Paint

    private lateinit var menu: NavigationBarMenu
    private lateinit var selectedListener: OnItemSelectedListener
    private lateinit var homeLongListener: OnHomeLongListener

    private val animDuration: Long = 450

    private var itemCount = 3
    private var itemSelectedWidth = 0

    private var previousItemSelectedWidth = 0

    private var itemId = 0
    private var previousItemId = 0

    private var halfCurveCurrent = 0f

    private var animating: Boolean = false


    init {

        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        labelVisibilityMode = LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED

        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CurvedBottomNavigation, 0, 0)
            .apply {
                try {
                    navBg = getColor(R.styleable.CurvedBottomNavigation_nav_bg, Color.WHITE)

                } finally {
                    recycle()
                }
            }

        path = Path()

        paint = Paint().apply {
            style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
            color = navBg
            setShadowLayer(8f, 0f, -1f, Color.parseColor("#30000000"))

        }

        paintFab = Paint().apply {
            style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
            color = navBg
            setShadowLayer(10f, 0f, 0f, Color.parseColor("#35000000"))

        }
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        bottomNavHeight = h
        bottomNavWidth = w
        itemSelectedWidth = (bottomNavWidth * 5) / (itemCount * 2)

        itemId = itemCount

        previousItemSelectedWidth = itemSelectedWidth

        halfCurveCurrent = curveOffset + (fabRadius / 3f)


    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

        setupPoint(previousItemSelectedWidth)
        createCurve()
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)

        canvas.drawCircle(previousItemSelectedWidth.toFloat(), fabY + 10f, fabRadius, paintFab)

        super.onDraw(canvas)

    }

    private fun setupPoint(w: Int) {

        startCurve.apply {
            x = w - curveOffset
            y = curveHeight
        }

        halfCurve.apply {
            x = w.toFloat()
            y = halfCurveCurrent
        }

        controlPoint1.apply {
            x = w - fabRadius
            y = curveHeight
        }

        controlPoint2.apply {
            x = halfCurve.x - fabRadius
            y = halfCurve.y
        }

        controlPoint3.apply {
            x = halfCurve.x + fabRadius
            y = halfCurve.y
        }

        controlPoint4.apply {
            x = w + fabRadius
            y = curveHeight
        }

        endCurve.apply {
            x = w + curveOffset
            y = curveHeight
        }


    }

    private fun createCurve() {

        path.reset()
        path.moveTo(bottomNavigationOffset, curveHeight)
        path.lineTo(startCurve.x, startCurve.y)
        path.cubicTo(
            controlPoint1.x,
            controlPoint1.y,
            controlPoint2.x,
            controlPoint2.y,
            halfCurve.x,
            halfCurve.y
        )
        path.cubicTo(
            controlPoint3.x,
            controlPoint3.y,
            controlPoint4.x,
            controlPoint4.y,
            endCurve.x,
            endCurve.y
        )
        path.lineTo(bottomNavWidth.toFloat(), curveHeight)
        path.lineTo(
            bottomNavWidth.toFloat() - bottomNavigationOffset,
            bottomNavHeight.toFloat() - bottomNavigationOffset
        )
        path.lineTo(bottomNavigationOffset, bottomNavHeight.toFloat() - bottomNavigationOffset)
        path.close()


    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun inflateMenu(resId: Int) {

        menu = NavigationBarMenu(context, this::class.java, 3)
        MenuInflater(context).inflate(resId, menu)
        itemCount = menu.maxItemCount

        if (MainActivity.preferences.getBoolean("dark_mode", true)) {
            menu[0].icon =
                AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.night_setting_fragment_icon)
            menu[1].icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
                context,
                R.drawable.night_schedule_management_fragment_icon
            )
            menu[2].icon =
                AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.night_main_fragment_icon)

        }

        doOnPreDraw {
            initItemViews()
        }

    }


    fun setupWithNavController(navController: NavController) {
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(this, navController)

    }

    override fun setOnItemSelectedListener(listener: OnItemSelectedListener?) {
        if (listener != null) {
            selectedListener = listener
        }
    }


    private fun initItemViews() {

        val iconList = arrayListOf<ImageView>()

        removeAllViews()
        val mainLinearLayout = LinearLayout(context)
        val bottomNavLayoutParams = LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.BOTTOM
        )

        for (item in menu) {

            val icon = ImageView(context)
            val iconParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                140, 1f
            )

            icon.layoutParams = iconParams

            if (item.order == itemId) {
                icon.y = (fabY + 10) - (icon.layoutParams.height / 2)
                icon.scaleX = 1.2f
                icon.scaleY = 1.2f
            } else
                icon.y =
                    bottomNavHeight.toFloat() - ((bottomNavHeight - fabRadius) / 2) - (icon.layoutParams.height / 2)

            icon.setImageDrawable(item.icon)
            icon.setOnClickListener {
                if (item.order != itemId && !animating) {
                    animating = true
                    previousItemId = itemId
                    itemId = item.order
                    selectedListener.onNavigationItemSelected(item)
                    itemSelectedWidth =
                        (bottomNavWidth * (1 + ((item.order - 1) * 2))) / (itemCount * 2)

                    hideAnimation(iconList[previousItemId - 1]).apply {
                        addListener(onEnd = {
                            previousItemSelectedWidth = itemSelectedWidth

                            showAnimation(icon).apply {
                                start()

                                addListener(onEnd = {
                                    animating = false
                                })
                            }
                        })
                        start()
                    }

                }

            }

            icon.setOnLongClickListener {
                if (item.order == 3 && item.order == itemId) {
                    homeLongListener.homeLongListener()
                }
                false
            }

            icon.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20)

            iconList.add(icon)
            mainLinearLayout.addView(icon)

        }

        addView(mainLinearLayout, bottomNavLayoutParams)

    }

    private fun hideAnimation(previousIcon: ImageView): AnimatorSet {

        val iconScaleAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(previousIcon.scaleX, 1f)
        iconScaleAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                previousIcon.scaleX = it.animatedValue as Float
                previousIcon.scaleY = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        val iconAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(
            previousIcon.y,
            (bottomNavHeight.toFloat() - ((bottomNavHeight - fabRadius) / 2) - (previousIcon.layoutParams.height / 2))
        )
        iconAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                previousIcon.y = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        val fabHideAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(fabRadius, fabRadius * 2)
        fabHideAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                fabY = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        val halfAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(halfCurve.y, fabRadius + 10)
        halfAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                halfCurveCurrent = it.animatedValue as Float
                invalidate()
            }
        }
        val fabShadowAnimator =
            ValueAnimator.ofArgb(Color.parseColor("#35000000"), Color.parseColor("#00000000"))
        fabShadowAnimator.apply {
            addUpdateListener {
                paintFab.setShadowLayer(10f, 0f, 0f, it.animatedValue as Int)

            }
        }
        val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
        animatorSet.playTogether(
            fabHideAnimator,
            halfAnimator,
            fabShadowAnimator,
            iconAnimator,
            iconScaleAnimator
        )
        animatorSet.duration = animDuration / 2
        animatorSet.interpolator = MotionUtils.resolveThemeInterpolator(
            context,
            com.google.android.material.R.attr.motionEasingEmphasizedAccelerateInterpolator,
            AccelerateInterpolator()
        )
        return animatorSet
    }

    private fun showAnimation(icon: ImageView): AnimatorSet {


        val iconScaleAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(icon.scaleX, 1.2f)
        iconScaleAnimator.apply {
            duration = animDuration
            addUpdateListener {
                icon.scaleX = it.animatedValue as Float
                icon.scaleY = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        val iconAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(
            icon.y,
            ((fabRadius + 10) - (icon.layoutParams.height / 2))
        )
        iconAnimator.apply {
            duration = animDuration
            addUpdateListener {
                icon.y = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }


        val fabHideAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(fabRadius * 2, fabRadius)
        fabHideAnimator.apply {
            duration = animDuration
            addUpdateListener {
                fabY = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        }

        val halfAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(fabRadius, curveOffset + (fabRadius / 3f))
        halfAnimator.apply {
            duration = animDuration
            addUpdateListener {
                halfCurveCurrent = it.animatedValue as Float

            }
        }

        val fabShadowAnimator =
            ValueAnimator.ofArgb(Color.parseColor("#00000000"), Color.parseColor("#35000000"))
        fabShadowAnimator.apply {
            duration = animDuration
            addUpdateListener {
                paintFab.setShadowLayer(10f, 0f, 0f, it.animatedValue as Int)
                invalidate()
            }
        }

        val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
        animatorSet.playTogether(
            fabHideAnimator,
            halfAnimator,
            fabShadowAnimator,
            iconAnimator,
            iconScaleAnimator
        )
        animatorSet.interpolator = MotionUtils.resolveThemeInterpolator(
            context,
            com.google.android.material.R.attr.motionEasingEmphasizedDecelerateInterpolator,
            DecelerateInterpolator()
        )
        return animatorSet
    }

    fun setOnHomeLongListener(homeLongListener: OnHomeLongListener) {
        this.homeLongListener = homeLongListener
    }

}
```